# On hover open a DIV, DIV content should dynamically load from a separate URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm sure someone has already done this and posted it online, but I'm having trouble finding such an example or tutorial.

Basically, I want to have a series of links on the page. If you hover your mouse on the link, it should open a drop down DIV box under the link and then load content into the DIV from a remote URL that is pre-defined.

Has anyone seen such an implementation or have any ideas on how to do it with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something similar to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").hover(function(){ //When a given link (<a> tag) is hovered over
       $("div").load(this.href).show(); //load the src of that tag into a given div container.
    });
});
```

Here's a simple test in jsFiddle, but I didn't know what to put with the href...so all you'll see is the div appear with the post error...not very pretty, but if anyone has suggestions then I'm definitely open to all.

http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/VEuH9/2/

Comment: Does `this` need to be `$(this)`?  Aside from that, great answer. I'd +1 but am out of votes.

Comment: I don't believe so. It should refer to the <a> element itself. I could be mistaken though, and if that's the case I can change it =) Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Mark, be sure to let us know which method works for you. Thanks! :)

Comment: @JonathanSampson - I thought something looked funny with that. Good find.

Comment: @JonathanSampson Yeah, I noticed that about the time you said it, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I was working on a jsFiddle for the example...I'm just not sure what to put for the href.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something like the following. Note that we target only anchors who don't have the `loaded` class. The reason why is because we don't want to load the contents for any anchor multiple times. Whenever the user passes over an anchor, its content will be loaded and it will get a special class indicated this. If they pass over it again, nothing happens.

```
$("body").on("mouseenter", "a:not(.loaded)", function(e){
  $(".mydiv").load(e.target.href, function(){
    $(e.target).addClass("loaded");
  });
});
```

Comment: you can just use this.href as in the other answer.

Comment: @LocalPCGuy I prefer to keep references consistent. Since I'm using the event-object reference within the callback, I decided to use it as well in the load method.

Comment: Guess I'm confused why you would use e.target rather than this in either case, but either way works just fine.  Consistency is good, and I liked that you use a class to prevent the function from continually firing.

Comment: @LocalPCGuy Because I can access `e` from anywhere, and it will always be the same. `this` will change depending on where it's called.

Comment: `e.target` is still wrong for this, `e.currentTarget` is what you want. `e.target` is not necessarily the anchor element.

Comment: @Esailija `e.target` is only wrong if the anchor has nested elements.

Comment: @JonathanSampson But the point is that `e.currentTarget` is always right. Trying to remember to change all code that has `e.target` when your markup changes is not much fun when it could have been easily avoided by using the correct reference in the first place.